# Setting enviroment variable in CircleCI using a command

Tags: circleci

I'm trying to set an environment variable (SHORT_HASH) to shorter github hash by running it as a command ('echo $CIRCLE_SHA1 | cut -c -7').

So, I'd want the hash 'b1e5ef8acff51c9218ccbf7152fae1d2049d03c5' to be shortened to 'b1e5ef8'

Here's a stripped down version of my circle.yml

```
machine:
  python:
    version: 2.7.3
  services:
    - docker
  environment:
    SHORT_HASH: 'echo $CIRCLE_SHA1 | cut -c -7'
    BUILD_TAG: $CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM-$SHORT_HASH
```

I looked at the circleci docs, but am not finding anything like this.  https://circleci.com/docs/environment-variables

Comment: Circle error was:  found character ` '`' that cannot start any token. (Do not use ` for indentation).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code is executed in a shell, so you'll want to use backticks or the $() method around the phrase you want to evaluate.  This this:

```
SHORT_HASH: $(echo $CIRCLE_SHA1 | cut -c -7)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work (anymore?), see https://circleci.com/gh/tesch1/OpenVnmrJ/72

Comment: I see you got it working.  You didn't need it with something like `OVJ_BUILDDIR: $(echo $HOME/OpenVnmrJBuild)` because you weren't (really) using any shell commands.  The example I showed needed the `cut` command, so we had to wrap the whole thing.

Comment: Yeah, I got it working by not using the `environment:` option at all.  What wasn't working was evaluating the $(...) , it was just escaping all of the special characters.  It also wasn't possible to do `OVJ_BUILDDIR: $HOME/blah`. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is to append export statement to `$BASH_ENV` 
Here is an example:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: buildpack-deps:jessie
    working_directory: ~/project
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: |
        bar_var="foo-bar"
        echo 'export FOO_ENV_VAR="${bar_var}"' >> $BASH_ENV
      - run:
          command: |
            echo $FOO_ENV_VAR
```